# Is this correct: It is I whom you saw in the window

Tags: pronouns, who-whom

While there's no problem with

> *It's me* **whom** you saw in the window.

if I prefer to use the formal

> *It is **I*** **whom** you saw in the window.

Am I required to follow up with the subject *who* pronoun or the object *whom* pronoun?
Seems like I'm breaking a rule whichever I choose.

Comment: @123 - I totally agree with you. I don't mean to be stringent.

Answer (score 4):

*Whom* is a relative pronoun in a relative clause, so it is not dependent on the case of the antecedent and *vice versa*.

Formal English marks *It is I* as more correct than *It is me*, though in colloquial speech we've recognized it as a [predicate accusative](http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2014/11/johnson-pronouns).

Edit: Also note karyse's point about the tense shift. That is less up for debate!

Answer (score 3):

Whichever may be correct for the "whom" construction, the sentence suffers from tense shift. To fix it either -- It *was* me that you *saw* in the window. Or, It is *I* that you *see* in the window.

Note that I intentionally changed the sentence to a more common construction in order to point out something that few people seem to know. The "for whom" and "for which" construction is the imposition of a Latin sentence structure on what should be a perfectly acceptable English sentence. Not ending a sentence in a preposition became a rule because of that imposition. Because the Church used Latin it became the language of the educated class. In their infinite wisdom they began attempting to change English. It didn't work and it probably never will.

Once I asked one of the wise people: Who are you going to the movies with?

He responded: You can't end a sentence with a preposition.

I answered: Okay, who are you going to the movies with moron?

Since he knew the rule, but not the rationale of the rule, he didn't know how to respond. Point for the anti-grammar police crowd.

It is always okay to break an English rule, so long as you know the rule to begin with and can reject it with intent.

If you must use the construction, "whom" is used for direct objects. Example: For whom are you looking? You can see that in "Who are you looking for?" Yes, another preposition.

Comment: +1 for this statement: "It is always okay to break an English rule, so long as you know the rule to begin with and can reject it with intent." Thank you.